# OBS studio 26.0.2 VST 2.x Plug-ins

Tags: sound, wine

The 26.0.02 version of OBS studio available at the PPA below includes a **VST 2.x Plug-in** audio filter wrapper.

```
https://launchpad.net/~obsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio
```

Has anyone figured out how to access any of the VST plugins in OBS? I can add the "VST 2.x Plug-in" to the filters from the dialog but then the drop-down "{Please select a plug-in}" menu is blank. I have plenty of VST plug-ins installed, I can see them in carla. I also installed the [reaper vst plugins](https://www.reaper.fm/reaplugs/) in wine and the 64-bit reaper vst plugins with wine64. Please suggest on how to get this working with OBS or the best way to verify at least some my VST plug-ins are working (typically I prefer the free native lv2 plug-ins).

Answer (score 0):

A work-around I've found that allows me to use both my VST plugins and all my other plugins too is to use jackd audio interface and a plugin manager like carla. Unfortunately, this requires that I have jackd running and setup every time I want to record a video or stream which is a little bit of a hassle.

Comment: So, you need both hardware and software just to have a work around? Also, do you know exactly which directory should we put the plugin to make it work?

Comment: What are you doing without hardware trying to record or stream audio and video? Jackd works on most of the built-in audio cards I have used you just have to be really generous with the amount of latency, and stingy with the bit depth and sample rate. So that would make realt-time streaming difficult, but if you're okay with 30 seconds delay you're fine. I'm not particularly happy with this work-around so that's why the question is still active. More recent versions of OBS may fix it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response I appreciate it. But you haven't answered my question regarding the exact location where you put the plugin files in your Ubuntu. Can you please provide some information on that. Thank you and GOD bless.

Comment: @Edper I haven't been using this much but you'd need another program to manage your VST pluggins. Here's the ubuntu setup link here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook/UsingVSTPlugins

Comment: Thank you very much @N8tron.